# Golang on Mac Run ok but compile error

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a simple script:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to Connect to Ethereum network: %v", err)
    }

NewAENToken(common.HexToAddress("0x0BEf619cF38cF0c22967289b8419720fBd1Db9f7"),conn)

    ctx := context.Background()
    tx, pending, _ := conn.TransactionByHash(ctx, common.HexToHash("0x30999361906753dbf60f39b32d3c8fadeb07d2c0f1188a32ba1849daac0385a8"))
    if !pending {
        fmt.Println(tx)
    }
}
```

When I run the command as such:

```
go run main.go
```

It runs, except without a clean layout. but when I execute the following:

```
go tool compile main.go
```

I get the following Error:

```
main.go:8:5: can't find import: "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
```

Things Tried are replacing the

```
"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
```

with

```
  "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/common"
```

which also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
That should be all u need. There is a easier way using home brew.  'brew tap ethereum/ethereum'
            'brew install ethereum'
Don't forget 'geth account new'

I am adding the Answer to your, as you were so kind to help. I found the problem.
relates to the compile command not including the GOPATH.
the build Command Works fine. I found the answer  here!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528836/import-path-difference-using-build-and-tool-compile

I give you the credit also.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this does not solve the problem, as you can see, it runs as expected, but does not compile. the suggestions have already been done previously. What is the purpose of geth account new? when all I am doing is compiling the Go?